# Pentaho CDE special chart

Tags: charts, pentaho, olap, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer

Is it possible to create a chart in Pentaho CDE like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08hS7.png) ?

I've tried many things and searched on the internet but found nothing.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This is customized chart, you can write HTML and CSS code and develop this types of functionality.
there is no such direct component available to develop this type of visualization.